# R match whole words in phrases

Tags: r, regex

I have a character vector

```
var1 <- c("pine tree", "forest", "fruits", "water")
```

and a list

```
var2 <- list(c("tree", "house", "star"),  c("house", "tree", "pine tree", "tree pine", "dense forest"), c("apple", "orange", "grapes"))
```

I want to match words in var1 with words in var2, and extract the maximum matching element in var2. For example,

```
[[1]]
[1] "tree"  "house" "star"
```

has 1 match with var1

```
[[2]]
[1] "house"        "tree"         "pine tree"    "tree pine"    "dense forest"
```

has 4 matches with var1

```
[[3]]
[1] "apple"  "orange" "grapes"
```

has 0 match with var1

And the desired output is the following:

```
[[2]]
[1] "house"        "tree"         "pine tree"    "tree pine"    "dense forest"
```

I tried

```
sapply(var1, grep,  var2, ignore.case=T, value=T)
```

without getting the output desired.

How to solve it? A code snippet would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please check the updated solution I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a pattern string ('pat') for the `grepl` , by first splitting the 'var1' by space `'\\s+'`.  The output will be a list.  We use `sapply` to loop over the list, use `paste` with `collapse= '|'`, and then collapse the whole vector to a single string with another `paste`.  The `|` acts as `OR` while using as pattern for `grepl` in `v1`. The `sum` vector ('v1') will be used for subsetting the `list` 'var2' based on the condition described in the question.

```
 pat <- paste(sapply(strsplit(var1, '\\s+'), function(x)
     paste(unique(c(x, paste(x, collapse=' '))), collapse='|')),
     collapse='|')
 v1 <- sapply(var2, function(x) sum(grepl(pat, x)))
 v1
 #[1] 1 4 0
 var2[which.max(v1)]
 #[[1]]
 #[1] "house"        "tree"         "pine tree"    "tree pine"    "dense forest"
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the code please, in particular, '\\s+' and collapse='|'

Comment: @john Added some text.  Hope it helps